# Ubuntu 22.04.1 cannot install libc6-dev because broken package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I tried to install `lib6-dev` librarby on Ubuntu 22.04 but it has this error

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                             
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                 
Hit:3 https://download.rasdaman.com/Download/deb jammy InRelease    
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
136 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

```
sudo apt-get install -f libc6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`? Any errors there?

Comment: @nobody yes, I ran it. Updated in the description. No errors

Comment: Start by upgrading your 136 un-upgraded packages: `sudo apt full-upgrade`. Then try again. I simulated installing `libc6-dev`, and on my fully upgraded system, there were no issues.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I managed to install by adding more repository in /etc/apt/sources.list. I added my solution in the description.

Comment: @BằngRikimaru Good to hear you got it resolve, but please don't add solutions in the *question* - That's what answers are for.  However, once a question has been identified as a duplicate, additional answers aren't allowed, since they should be posted on the *original* question.  In this case, it looks to me like your answer is the same as one that's already present on, ["How do I restore the default repositories?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories), so there's no reason to post again.

Comment: If you disagree with the closure, and you feel your question isn't a duplicate, you can ask for second opinions on [meta.askubuntu.com](https://meta.askubuntu.com).  Or if you feel you have a unique solution to one of the existing questions, you can also post it there.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Your link to https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories is ambiguous to my problem and the marked answer is outdated to Ubuntu 12.04, and my problem happened in Ubuntu 22.04 and for this library particularly. So I disagree with you.